# Using property placeholders for a String in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I have a bean configuration file and have to set a property for URL which is a `String`. I want to borrow these values from property files.

```
<camel:to uri="<This is the String which i want from properties file>"/>
```

The string should be like

```
example.com?from=${property1}&to=${property2}
```

`property1` and `property2` are present in properties file.

I tried using SpEL and I am using Spring 3.1 but I get the following error

```
invalid charecter at index 0
```

This is the EL i tried

```
<camel:to uri="#{example.com?from=${property1}&to=${property2}}"/>
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Do you use camel inside a spring context file?